# How to filter only text in a line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have many lines like these:

```
_ÙÓ´Immediate Transformation With Vee_ÙÓ´
‰ÛÏThe Real Pernell Stacks‰Û
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Immediate Transformation With Vee
The Real Pernell Stacks
```

I tried this:

```py
for t in test:
    t.isalpha()
```

but characters like this `Ó` count as well

So I also thought that I can create a list of English words, a space and punctuation marks and delete all the elements from the line that are not in this list, but I do not think that this is the right option, since the line can contain not only English words and that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = """_ÙÓ´Immediate Transformation With Vee_ÙÓ´
‰ÛÏThe Real Pernell Stacks‰Û"""

for line in data.splitlines(keepends=False):
    print(re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z\s]", "", line))
```

**Output:**

```
Immediate Transformation With Vee
The Real Pernell Stacks
```

Comment: how can I add ```(),.'!"-```  to the exception?

Comment: `re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z\s(),.'!\"-]", "", line)` ?

Answer (score 1):

use `re`

```
result = ' '.join(re.split(r'[^A-Za-z]', s))
```

Comment: Doesn't clear the white spaces: `'    Immediate Transformation With Vee        The Real Pernell Stacks  '`